# Get JWT token in redux

Tags: node.js, redux, jwt

I am using JWT to handle authentication and I have a update new password function. My problem is that how do I pass this JWT to my server in the UpdatePasswordAction ? Actually, I have that JWT in my cookies but when I submit the data to the server, the data is not passed correctly. Do I pass it right?

From my server, the JWT can not be retrieved.

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.cookies));//  -> {} 
  console.log(req.headers.authorization);// -> undefined
```

[image]

In my User.actions.jsx, what I want to do is to get the token stored in cookies and pass the updatePasswordState which contains  current password, new password, and new confirmed password.

```
import { Cookies } from 'js-cookie';

export const UpdatePasswordAction = (updatePasswordState) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try { 
           // what I do is to pass the new password and JWT to the server to handle new password update
            const token = Cookies.get('jwt');
            const res = await axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/updateMyPassword`, updatePasswordState, token);
            const { data } = res;
            dispatch({ type: UserActionTypes.UPDATE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, payload: data });
            alert('Update Password Successfully');
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                dispatch({
                    type: UserActionTypes.UPDATE_PASSWORD_FAIL,
                    payload: error.response.data.message,
                });
                console.log(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

In my server, I have a middleware to check whether the user is login or not.

```
exports.protect = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  //Getting token and check of it's there
  let token;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.cookies));//  -> {} 
  console.log(req.headers.authorization);// -> undefined

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  } else if (req.cookies.jwt) {
    token = req.cookies.jwt;
  }

  if (!token) {
    return next(
      new AppError('You are not logged in! Please log in to get access.', 401)
    );
  }

// rest jwt decode and verification
});
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly sending the data to the server. The [axios#patch](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiospatchurl-data-config) signature is this:

```
axios#patch(url[, data[, config]])
```

So you should change it to something like this:

```js
await axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/updateMyPassword`, updatePasswordState, {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": token
  }
});
```

And on your server side you can access the Authorization header with `req.headers.authorization`